# PostgreSQL trigger "WHEN" does not work

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I got a table with a timestamp field that must be updated after a row change. 
Function `change_update_time()` updates timestamp field that is called `updated_time`.
My trigger works just fine, but i can't add more `WHEN` clauses(system just ignores them all).

Code:

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_updated_time_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON data_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( 
    (OLD.column1 <> NEW.column1) AND
    (OLD.column2 <> NEW.column2) 
  )
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_update_time();
```

This is my trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_update_time()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
  NEW.updated_time = now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1;
```

Database version: PostgreSQL 9.3.4

Comment: We need a table definition for basic info. What you get with `\d data_table` in `psql`.

Comment: Presumably you want `OLD.colname IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.colname` instead of  `OLD.colname<>NEW.colname`, otherwise the trigger will not execute when `NULL` values are involved.

Comment: Why do you want to add more `WHEN` clauses? You've already found the solution: just concatenate them with `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Also, if you want to extend your trigger's `WHEN` clause after each column you've added, you could just use row-wise comparison: `WHEN OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW` or (for just some columns): `WHEN ROW(OLD.c1, OLD.c2, OLD.c3) IS DISTINCT FROM ROW(NEW.c1, NEW.c2, NEW.c3)` (but this will work like there was `OR` between your comparisons, your example trigger will activate only if both of your columns changed at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause (not enough information to be sure):

Your conditions do not catch any changes from / to NULL. Either `column1` and `column2` are defined `NOT NULL` or you need to adapt:

```
WHEN (OLD.column1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column1 AND
      OLD.column2 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column2)
```

Another typical cause: other triggers intervening. You'd have to list *all* triggers in the question.